# Compress image asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, compression

i am new for asp.net . I having a problem now. I need to compress my image before storing to my database. I googling quite lot time.

But most of the tutorial is guiding me need to resize the width and height before store to the database. so nw is my question is it possible to compress the image without **resize the width and height** before store to the database. Please guide me solution .

For instance http://compressnow.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [GZIP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx)

```
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
byte[] compressedFileBytes = Compress(fileBytes); //compress
byte[] decompressedFileBytes = Decompress(compressedFileBytes); //decompress

byte[] Compress(byte[] b)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (GZipStream z = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
            z.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        return ms.ToArray();
   }
}
byte[] Decompress(byte[] b)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var bs = new MemoryStream(b))
        using (var z = new GZipStream(bs, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            z.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. Btw should i need to decompress the image file if i want to show image in my panel?

Comment: Image formats are already compressed, so that will get you nothing by excess overhead. There are tools like PNGCrush,etc you could use from a command line (you can execute command line apps within C# FWIW). You can also use services like kraken.io and their API to optimize images as well. I am not sure storing them in a database is the best option in my experience. But its not my project so...:)